# Android: i need to do a menu like the image

Tags: java, android, jquery, ios, menu

i'm developing an application for android that is already done for IOS, is not big problem.
the thing is that my boss want it to be exactly the same, but one of the menus is the problem, is like a slide menu but with zoom and a background image, anyone have any idea how can i do this, i already google it but no results :(, a library would help.

here is a picture with the menu for IOS.

[image: http://maniacdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/TWTSideMenuViewController.gif]

Comment: I believe I found your answer.  Check out updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

I think I found your answer.  I came across this in a list of libraries it is 3.8 on the list https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if it would be an effective solution but you can use a RelativeLayout. 
Put the selection part behind in a LinearLayout then put a framelayout front to contain list fragments. This way you shouldn't use an action bar to have absolutely same looking with iOs version.

When someone clicks open button apply an animation to your framelayout. scale it by %75 and move it 25% in y coordinate and move it %50 in x coordinate. When buttons in your LinearLayout apply a reverse animation to your FrameLayout. If swap button clicked change your fragment with new one. You can also aply a transaction animation to your fragments.

I hope you know how to handle this stuff. If no I can do my best to code an example.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to set your flame layout unclickable when you move it to right side.